# Google AdMobs interstitial on reopening timed out

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I would like to add some ads in my application, and especially an interstitial when the app enter foreground.

I've created this method in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)splashInterstitial
{
    UIImage *image;

    if (TEST_IPHONE_5) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h.png"];
    } else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    }

    splashInterstitial_ = [[DFPInterstitial alloc] init];
    splashInterstitial_.adUnitID = ADMOBS_OUVERTURE;
    [splashInterstitial_ loadAndDisplayRequest:[GADRequest request]
                                   usingWindow:self.window
                                  initialImage:image];

}
```

I call it twice : 
- in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`

It works fine when called in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but in the second case, I have this error :

> Google Request Error: The Google Ad request was unable to be fulfilled
>   before a timeout occurred.

Obviously, it needs 5 seconds to load, but I can't figure out how to force my application to wait for it.

Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to have my interstitial on my first launch but also each time the app gets active.

You only have to call my method `(void)splashInterstitial` once, in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` .

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    // ADMobs
    [self splashInterstitial];

}


- (void)splashInterstitial
{
    UIImage *image;

    if (TEST_IPHONE_5) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h.png"];
    } else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    }

    splashInterstitial_ = [[DFPInterstitial alloc] init];
    splashInterstitial_.adUnitID = ADMOBS_OUVERTURE;
    [splashInterstitial_ loadAndDisplayRequest:[GADRequest request]
                                   usingWindow:self.window
                                  initialImage:image];

}
```

Comment: i have tried this code in xcode 6.1.Admob Sdk is 6.12.2.i seen official Google admob Tutorial but there is no code in official site.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the `loadAndDisplayRequest:usingWindow:initialImage:` method. [This blog post](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/create-your-own-version-of.html) explains how you can achieve the same thing by using GADInterstitial's `loadRequest:` method. This implementation is better because you have more control over your view hierarchy.